# Wordpress custom endpoint returning blank response

Tags: rest-api

I have written some custom endpoints in wordpress plugin. Previously when i used wp_send_json to return data from custom endpoint. But as of wordpress 5.5 the usage of wp_send_json is deprecated. Now Iam returning WP_REST_Response from the custom endpoint. But when i try the request after this logic change Iam getting blank responses.

Here is the code iam using to send response from callback.

```
public static function sendJSON($data)
    {
        $response             = [];
        $response = ["result" => $data['data'], "result_length" => sizeof($data['data']), "status_message" => "Success", "status" => $data['status']];
        
        return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);
    }
```

Comment: Why would [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) be deprecated? But yes, you wouldn't use it when returning a response from your REST API endpoint. And I suggest you to check (again) the REST API [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: @SallyCJ It is not deperecated but for wordpress 5.5 onwards the ideal way is to use the WP_Rest_Response from callback. But when i use it i'am not getting back any data. Only empty response is received in client with 200 status code.

Comment: By "blank responses", you mean the response was completely blank, or is it an empty array (`[]`)? How do you call the `sendJSON()`, what is the `$data`, and can you show your `register_rest_route()` code?

Comment: Is `sendJSON` the callback function? Or is it called by the callback function? If the latter, please include that code.

Comment: @SallyCJ
[link]https://justpaste.it/6fqgo
When i try the url getting completely blank response

Comment: @AlbertKP, you should edit your question and add [that information](https://justpaste.it/6fqgo) to your question. And from what I could tell, your functions need to return the result back to your REST API callback (`homepageData()`) - i.e. `return ClassName::homePage();` and `return ClassName::sendJSON($json_response);`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for your reply. It was a logic issue in my end. Thanks for helping out.